# SpriteKit how to have a label on screen change during runtime

Tags: sprite-kit

I have added a label to my scene with the following code:

```
    SKLabelNode *myLabel = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    myLabel.name = @"scoreCounter";
    myLabel.text = ;
    myLabel.fontSize = 30;
    myLabel.position = CGPointMake(50, 25);
    [self addChild:myLabel];
```

How can i have the label display a number that will change when my objects reach a certain x point? Or is there a way to have the label change whenever a node is removed from its parent. Basically, whenever one of my objects reach 360 on the x axis, i want the label to go up one, to represent score. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have named this label,you can find this label by it's name,and change the text.

```
SKLabelNode *node = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"scoreCounter"];
node.text = @"other string";
```